# make pop up stay on page upon saving (colorbox)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup, colorbox

I have a form which you can edit the user. this form is shown as a pop up (I am using colorbox plugin). After i click save, i want it to stay on the pop up page instead of closing the popup so i can display a text like "successfully saved info". Right now, whenever i click on save it closes the popup form and returns to the previous page. Can i make my popup stay upon  saving? Any help is appreciated

VIEW

```
  $('.openDialog').colorbox({
                  transition: "elastic",
                  width: "40%", height: "80%"
              });
```

CONTROLLER

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel vm)
          {
                Save(vm);
                return View(vm);
          }
```

VIEW

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" class="openDialog"/>
```

tried using ajax form submit but popup doesn't go to the controller, i added the unobtrusive script to the page and web config as well as jquery 1.8 still not good

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "User",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }))
```

Comment: use ajax callback to your controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use colorbox with the iframe property set to true.  When you show the form initially, add the parameter `iframe: true`.

Don't call `$.colorbox` again on the click, so your input tag in the view should just be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
```

When you click the submit button, the form submit occurs, and the results will return in the same colorbox iframe.  Colorbox is internally using AJAX and creating the iframe to handle all of this for you, nothing could be easier.

To see this approach in action, View http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/, and look at the iFrame example called "Outside Webpage (iFrame)", where it gets a Wiki search page, then submits the form, all within the same colorbox.

Comment: Thanks! this is a nice feature for colorbox. MArked as answer

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is your form is submitting, most likely to that same page, so the page "reloads", but with the submitted form data.

In order to do what you want, you'll have to make your form submit via ajax. This way the form submits via javascript and you won't get the page reload.

In this case, instead of your controller returning a view, it would return a status message letting you know if the submit was successful (and anything else you would need to update the page).

Comment: do i need to make my form a partial to use ajax.beginform?